# Scraping tables vertically

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Let me start out by saying I hate asking a pretty blind "please write it for me" style question as I usually relish learning things like this myself, but I'm in a time crunch. On top of that, yesterday was the first I learned of the existence of BeautifulSoup and I haven't done any real scripting or coding in about 7 years, so here I am.

In short, I'm trying to create a scraper to loop through several pages containing a table arranged vertically and output the data to csv.  So in the first pass, I'd need to read the first column to create a header row in my CSV, then for the rest of the URLs, just the second column to create the data rows. I think I can figure out how to loop through an input file with the URLs, but if anyone has a quick tidbit on that my plan is an input file with a url on each row.

The table is coded horribly, with tons of whitespace and carriage returns, but I think I've got that taken care of.  Where I'm getting stuck is looping through the columns vertically.  For the sake of ease, the table structure looks like this:

```html
<div id="mydiv">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>header 1</td>
        <td>value 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>header 2</td>
        <td>value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>header 3</td>
        <td>value 3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My 30 minutes of google fun yesterday got me to where I could pull the table out to CSV and strip all the extra characters. It's the first on the page, and has no ID, but what I wrote is only outputting that table so far.  The DIV the table is in does seem to have a unique ID, so if it comes to it I can probably isolate to that.

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
url="https://myurl.com/"
html = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
table = soup.find("table")

output_rows = []
for table_row in table.findAll('tr'):
    columns = table_row.findAll('td')
    output_row = []
    for column in columns:
         output_row.append(' '.join(column.text.split()))
    output_rows.append(output_row)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(output_rows)
```

That gets me the table scraped into a horizontal format (though there's an extra line between each line of data in the CSV that I haven't figured out yet).  But what I need is to scrape it vertically, across multiple URLs, and end up with a CSV that looks like:

```
header1,header2,header3
value1,value2,value3
value1,value2,value3 (from next URL in the list)
value1,value2,value3 (from next url in the list and so on)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no more info i guess this will help you a little:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
html = '''<div id="mydiv">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>header 1</td>
        <td>value 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>header 2</td>
        <td>value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>header 3</td>
        <td>value 3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>'''
num = 0
headers = []
values = []
rows = []
while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    trs = soup.select('div#mydiv tr')
    for t in trs:
        for header, value in zip(t.select('td')[0], t.select('td')[1]):
            if num == 0:
                headers.append(header)
            values.append(value)
    rows.append(values)
    values = []
    num += 1
    if num > 50:
        break
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns= headers)
print(df.head())

df.to_csv('mycsv.csv')
```

prints:

```
  header 1 header 2 header 3
0  value 1  value 2  value 3
1  value 1  value 2  value 3
2  value 1  value 2  value 3
3  value 1  value 2  value 3
4  value 1  value 2  value 3
```

and so on...
And saves the data to a file named `mycsv.csv`.

[image: csv]

The csv file first 30 rows

In this code i run a loop on your example html code 50 times to generate more values to the data. But you need to make a new request fore each page and soup it but i guess you understand. This is only a POC how you can make your code.

Comment: Thanks! I think I can work with that. One question.  Am I reading the code right that you're using the "num" variable so that the header is only added to the data the first loop (and you added a break, but assuming I won't need that once I add the input file with URLs).  Is that correct?

Comment: yes.. when `num = 0` the headers will be copied and not later. And you can change `while` loop to `for` loop and loop thru link list.

Comment: Have done so, but as I'm new it apparently doesn't show yet.